# How to return one of the parameters of a NSubstitute mocked method that is async. System.InvalidCastException

Tags: .net, xunit, nsubstitute

I have the following code that compiles.

```cs
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task ThisShouldWork()
    {
        // arrange
        var dto = new Dto
        {
            FName = "John",
            LName = "Doe"
        };
        
        var mock = Substitute.For<IRepository>();
        mock
            .SaveAsync(Arg.Any<DomainObject>())
            .Returns(args => args[0]);
        var service = new BusinessService(mock);
        
        // act
        var result = await service.DoSomethingAsync(dto);
        
        // assert
        await mock
            .Received(1)
            .SaveAsync(result);
    }
}

public class BusinessService
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public BusinessService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<DomainObject> DoSomethingAsync(Dto dto)
    {
        var domain = new DomainObject
        {
            FirstName = dto.FName,
            LastName = dto.LName
        };

        return await _repository.SaveAsync(domain);
    }
}

public class DomainObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    Task<DomainObject> SaveAsync(DomainObject domain);
}

public class Dto
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
}
```

However, if I run the test I get a `System.InvalidCastException`.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'DomainObject' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[DomainObject]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
.Returns(args => args.Arg<DomainObject>());
```

or alternatively

```
.Returns(args => args.ArgAt<DomainObject>(0));
```

The problem with `args[0]` is that it returns `object` and therefore the compiler won't take the `Returns<T>()` extension method overload on `Task<T>` which automatically wraps the result in a task for you.

An explicit cast should also work, but I don't like such code:

```
.Returns(args => (DomainObject)args[0]);
```

Comment: This is much better @cremor. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your method returns a `Task<DomainObject>` but your Returns() is returning a `DomainObject`. Since NSubstitute does not have a ReturnsAsync, you need to return a `Task<DomainObject>` via the Returns() method.

```
.Returns(args => Task.FromResult(args[0]));
```

Or, if this is a common pattern in your tests, you might be able to create an extension method to create a ReturnsAsync method that wraps this for you.

Comment: One side note: I do believe the author  missing the point a bit with the test: one has to check what is returned from the method, not only that some call is received.

Otherwise one can just change the code to something like 

await repository.SaveAsync(domainObject); return new DomainObject {};  And the test will still pass. 

So the test should use assertion comparing the results received with that expected

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't compile. I have posted how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up resolving it.

```cs
.Returns(args => Task.FromResult((DomainObject)args[0]));
```

**EDIT**
I ended up using @cremor 's solution.

```cs
.Returns(args => args.ArgAt<DomainObject>(0));
```